# How to make sure a night date doesn't continue to the bedroom?

Tags: huniepop

After a while, as you keep playing the game to unlock things, you'll often need to go on a night date with a girl you've already... let's say "conquered".

However, I find the bedroom bonus game to be a pain, despite the soundscape. What would be the best way to get the benefits of the night date (mostly the muney), but skip the bedroom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware if you go on a night date with a girl that you have advanced that far you *will* end up in the bedroom with her if you succeed in the date. Thus the two ways to avoid ending up in the bedroom after a night date are:

1. Fail the date
2. Go on a date with a girl that you haven't
   progressed with enough.

Neither of these are what you want really - failing the date means losing some of the benefits and you have indicated that you are asking about situations when all available girls are sufficiently advanced to end in the bedroom. Sadly sometimes there is no good answer to your problem.

Comment: I guess the next question would be how to loose on purpose effectively.

Comment: I'm afraid that I haven't ever really done this so can't comment, I've always tried to win. Its also been a while since I last played so can't really remember it that well. :(